# Session failover with memcache and php 7

Tags: php, session, memcached, php-7, failover

I try to setup session failover based on php7 with memcache.so.
I was settings up this functionality on php5.6 with same configs and it works perfectly. But it does not work on php 7.0/7.1/7.2.

My php.ini config:

```
session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = 'tcp://server1:11211, tcp://server2:11211'
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.session_redundancy = 3
```

PHP script for testing:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['cnt'])) {
    $_SESSION['cnt'] = 0;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cnt'] += 1;
}

echo $_SESSION['cnt'];
```

With php5.6 session data writes on both servers. I can restart memcached servers one by one and counter keeps incrementing while page reloading. Session data exists in each memcached server.

If I use php7, session data exists in both memcached servers. But counter resets, when I restart one of memcached servers and refresh page. And no data available in each server after that.